# How to make these four symbols in Latex?

Tags: symbols

How to input these symbols in Latex?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) To find how to produce symbols in LaTeX, you can go to either [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). If your symbols do not appear, either they are produced by a package not listed on these sources or they are user defined. In the last case, you will have to define them yourself and, in this case, you should provide an attempt of what you have tried so far and which abstract issue you are stuck with.

Comment: The symbols doesn't appear in  Detexify. They come from a Math paper about graph theory as  subscripts of certain variable.

Comment: You can draw them in a `\tikz{ } ` environment and use it as regular characters. It may be a good idea to put this drawing inside a `\newcommand\dotsa[0]{} ` and call the macro in "text like this: \dotsa{}" .

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With standard picture mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
% call \triad{000} or \triad{100} or \triad{011} or \triad{111}
\newcommand{\triad}[1]{\mathord{\,\triad@#1\,}}

% the main command
\newcommand{\triad@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.19ex}%
  \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}%
  \begin{picture}(8,7)
  \put(0,0){\circle*{2}}
  \put(8,0){\circle*{2}}
  \put(4,6.93){\circle*{2}}
  \ifodd#1 \Line(0,0)(8,0)\fi
  \ifodd#2 \Line(8,0)(4,6.93)\fi
  \ifodd#3 \Line(0,0)(4,6.93)\fi
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text $\triad{000}, \triad{100}, \triad{011}, \triad{111}$

$\triad{000}
\triad{001}
\triad{010}
\triad{011}
\triad{100}
\triad{101}
\triad{110}
\triad{111}$

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\triad` is a three-bit number; 1 means that the segment is drawn and the lower bit denotes the base, going around in anticlockwise rotation (see the whole lot in the picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Here is a start point:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=5,color=black,fill=black]
\tikzset{new/.style={color=black,line width=2pt}}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B,0.5/0.866/C}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}, 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B,0.5/0.866/C}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[line width=2pt](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}, 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B,0.5/0.866/C}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[line width=2pt](A,C B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}, 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,1/0/B,0.5/0.866/C}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[line width=2pt](A,C B,C A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]